# Product of Sums for a 4 variable fucntion without a truth table

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

> Represent the next function as product of sums by simplyfing the
> expression:
> $F(A,B,C,D) = B^{c}A(C^{c}D + B) + (B⊕C)$

We've been given our first assignment in boolean algebra and I've been going around and around this spesific question.

I've created a truth table and figured out what the product of sums should be, but I just can't figure out how to reach the result using the identities we've seen so far and I feel like there is something I'm missing..

Is there any trick involved in solving this?

Comment: Make a truth table first! (This will be a little tedious...)

Comment: Hi, I did! But I need to show it in both ways.. :(